# Equivalent of fs.readFile() -> to -> HTML upload in DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a binary file to an API by mostly retrofitting some existing js.

**The big difference between the existing and mine:**

*Use Node to import the binary file and send to API (what I need)*

**vs**

*Upload binary file from browser/html and send to API (existing)*

My efforts in using fs.readFile() have proven unsuccessful.
When inspecting the existing script (link below), there's nothing special happening to the file before sent to the API...

You can see the existing code/script in action here: https://api.pvpgn.pro/example/d2edit/
https://github.com/pvpgn/api.pvpgn.pro/blob/master/WebAPI/wwwroot/example/d2edit/index.html

```html
// Main culprit///
async function readSave() {
    fs.readFile('asdgasdgasdg.d2s', async function read(err, data) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        if (data){
            uploadFile(data, 'charinfo')
        }
    })
}

//// CODE BELOW WORKS WITH FILE UPLOAD FROM WEBPAGE /////
function uploadFile(file, type) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formData = new FormData();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);

    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange',
        function (e) {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                // Done. Inform the user
                var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(json);
                if (json.result === "error") {
                    if (type === 'charinfo') {
                        // try the same file with charsave type
                        uploadFile(file, 'charsave');
                    } else {
                        return throwError(json.errorMessage);
                    }
                } else {
                    charObjects.push(json.data);
                    var idx = charObjects.length - 1; // get last element index
                    charObjects[idx].idx = idx; // add new field with index

                    if (json.data.fileType !== 'charinfo' && json.data.fileType !== 'charsave') {
                        return throwError("Unsupported file type"); // charitem
                    }
                }
            } else if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status !== 200) {
                // Error. Inform the user
                console.log("error");
            }
        })
    
    formData.append('file', file);
    
    xhr.send(formData)
    xhr.onload = function() {
        // See response incase it failed...
        console.log(xhr)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

FormData() from npm does not work in the same capacity as the browsers.

I found request and it's request.form() to work great!

```html
    var req = request.post({url, form}, function (err, resp, body) {
        // console.log(resp)
        console.log(form)
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error!');
        } else {
          console.log('URL: ' + body);
        }
      });
    var form = req.form();
    form.append('file', fs.createReadStream('asdgasdgasdg.d2s'));
```